# Tomcat Web Application Manager Not Listing Deployed App

Tags: java, tomcat, deployment, apache-tomee

I uploaded myapp.war file to server using **Tomcat Web Application Manager**
It upload myapp.war file but does not list in List of application.

myapp.war file  and myapp (unzipped folder) is inside **wepapps** folder but also not listed in Application list. It only shows the default applications only.

Then i tried to upload again the same file and got error file already exists.

Why is it not listing the app though it is deployed?

[image]

Comment: Not an answer, however, try uploading it via terminal. I've had several problem using this UI (including this one) and I found just using terminal is better. Also check if the file is in the webapps folder in terminal as well

Comment: I already checked and made sure that the both war and extracted folder exists inside webapps folder.

Comment: And have you tried to turn on tomcat and access your webapp on a browser?

Comment: I am able to access the default apps like docs from browser..

Comment: but not you own apps?

Comment: no, i am unable to  access myapp

i tried ip:8080/myapp

Comment: There are deployment errors. Check your TomEE log file.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. Even though tomcat manager says app is deployed successfully, you might be able to find the relevant issues in the catalina log.

```
<tomcat_home>/logs/catalina.xxxx-xx-xx.log
```